# Combining items into fixed sized groups for k-d tree

Tags: algorithm, raytracing, kdtree

I'm using a k-d tree for spacial partitioning in a ray-tracer. I want to combine near-by primitives into fixed-sized groups so the data in each group can be deinterleaved and processed simultaneously using SIMD instructions. What is a good fast algorithm to find the (approximately) smallest fixed-sized groups?

Ideally it would augment the k-d tree building algorithm instead of adding a separate pass, but this is complicated by the fact that the primitives are normally so close together that most primitives will belong to more than one leaf node and I can't have groups with duplicate items because floating point precision errors would mess up shadows and reflections.

I figure I'm far from the first person to try this so a solution already exists, but the most relevant solutions I found from searching the internet for grouping objects deal with point data and variable-sized groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One popular way to group objects it to pick a random object, then add the "closest" *k* objects to a group with it.  "Closest" is usually defined to mean giving the smallest surface area for the combined bounding box.  You can also use the [Hilbert curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) distance; either the distance on the 3D curve between the objects' centers, or in 6D space where the bounding boxes become points:

```
(x_min, y_min, z_min, x_max, y_max, z_max)
```

Comment: The "popular" way to group objects that you describe is exactly what I want, but there are simply too many combinations to check all of them. For example: with 10000 items and a group size of 4, there would be C(10000,4) + C(9996,4) + C(9992,4) + ... + C(4,4) possibilities (where "C" is the combination function), which is equal to over 208 quadrillion.

Comment: As for the Hilbert curve: it looks promising, but it looks like it only works with integer coordinates, so I would need to pick a resolution to map to, which has its own complications depending on how densely the items are packed and how uniformly they are spread.

Comment: @Rouslan You don't need to check every combination.  Pick an object, find the *k* closest objects to it.  Pick another object, etc.  This is only n^2.  Then a trick is to start building the k-d tree, and do the grouping once there's a small number of candidate objects left.

Comment: Right, I wasn't thinking straight. Actually it seems to be even less than n^2. Anyway, I think I will do it this way, but also sort all the items first, by one of the dimensions, so that to find the k closest objects, I search left and right of an object and can stop once I found k objects and the distance along that dimension of subsequent objects exceeds the maximum actual distance of the closest k objects found so far.

Comment: @Rouslan That's a great idea if you can spare the space and the time for three/six full sorts.

Comment: Thanks. I actually meant I would sort _only_ one dimension (the longest dimension of the bounding box of the entire scene). It would mean a lot of adjacent items are actually very far apart, but the search could still terminate early once some close items are found.